# Организация приватных сообщений в чате

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю мини-чат, нужно сделать приватные сообщения, типа:
если я написал `"private [Антон,Лиза,Максим] привет, доброго утра!"`, то сообщение будет доступно 3 этим людям. Я сделал с занесением строки из `[]` в поле в БД и последующий поиск через `LIKE`.
Вопрос: это нормальное решение? Может я заблуждаюсь и этот вариант при большей нагрузке станет неприемлим?

Comment: @ROOT, не могу там писать, лимит на комменты. Я же говорю, два `"Антон"` быть не может - это уникальный ник. С этим проблем нет. Просто я для примера ников взял имена. Можно `",Construct,ROOT,Palmervan"`))

Comment: @sercxjo, нет, у меня будет куда больше десятка. А каким методом можно сделать не медленно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормальное решение - нормализованная БД, извините за тавтологию. Поскольку отношение "многие ко многим", вводим дополнительную таблицу (userid, messageid).

Comment: А, то есть для каждого сообщения создавать несколько записей с одним `messageid`, но с разными `userid` для всех получателей?

Comment: да, столько записей, сколько получателей, но основное сообщение в другой таблице

Answer (score 0):

Нужно писать как минимум уникальный идентификаторы с базы данных, потому как Антонов, Лиз и Максимов может быть много, и может не совсем те, что нужны. А вообще лучше писать уникальные сообщения при приватном чате, которое может читать, только пользователь, у которого например `to` - наш юзер

Comment: Извините, я неясно описал, под Антон и ко я имел в виду уникальные логины юзеров, ессно, а не имена просто.  
"А вообще лучше писать уникальные сообщения при приватном чате, которое может читать, только пользователь, у которого например to - наш юзер" - не понял, всмысле типа юзеры создают комнаты чата? Не, это у меня будет лишне, мне просто надо обычную отправку.

Comment: А это тогда к чему "последующий поиск через LIKE."?

Comment: @ROOT, то есть, когда Антон зайдёт в чат, личные сообщения для него будут найдены, через что-то типа `SELECT ... WHERE to LIKE 'Антон'`
А в самом поле `to`, к примеру, `Антон,Лиза,Максим`

Comment: говорю же я бы плясал от уникальных идентификаторов пользователей... и тогда все Ваши проблемы решены

Comment: @ROOT, вы хотите сказать, уникальных `id` юзеров? А в чём тогда с ними будет капитальная разница? Записывать в `to` через запятую не имена, а id?  
P.S.: да проблем то у меня пока и нет, я просто интересуюсь правильностью такого решения.

Comment: 'Антонина' LIKE '%Антон%' - получит сообщение

Comment: а если два Антона в чате

Comment: @sercxjo, про это я сразу подумал, я буду в to записывать вот так:
`",Антон,Максим,Лиза,"` и запрашивать `"LIKE %,Антон,%"`, просто не стал писать.

Comment: В общем будет компактно но медленно, если у вас с десяток юзеров, то сойдёт